# Mounting an extenal drive

Tags: permissions, mount

I manually tried to mount this drive and got this message:

```
mohamed@Orion:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mynewdrive The disk
    contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in Windows
    cache, refused to mount. Falling back to read-only mount because the
    NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
    Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting.)
```

---

Comment: Yes, what is the question ?

Comment: As the error message suggests have you fully shutdown Windows? Or you can try mounting in read only mode using `sudo mount -o ro /dev/sdb1 /media/mynewdrive`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following utility:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

from the man page:

> ntfsfix repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS
>   journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first
>   boot into Windows